# How to attach multiple embedded images in mail body using for loop win32 python

Tags: python, email, win32com

I am exporting images from excel and I want to attach the all images in outlook email as embedded images. 
My code is below which export the images but while adding to mail body only last image is being attached. While sending as attachment all images are being selected.

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import win32com.client as win32
import xlrd
from win32com import client
import base64

path=
excel =win32.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open("path to file")
RNC = xlrd.open_workbook("path to file")
outlook = client.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.Display() # required to paste chart
mail.To = 'xyz'
mail.Subject = 'Daily Report'
#exporting images from excel
l=[]
RNC_list = RNC.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
for x in range(1,RNC_list.nrows):
    for cell in RNC_list.row(x):
        l.append(cell.value)
for sheet in workbook.Worksheets:
    if sheet.name in l:
        for i, shape in enumerate(sheet.Shapes):
            if shape.Name.startswith('Picture'):
                shape.Copy()
                image = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
                image.save(path + r"\Pic" + sheet.name+str(i) + ".png")
                filename = path + r"\Pic" + sheet.name+str(i) + ".png"
                attachment= mail.Attachments.Add(filename)
                attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", "{}".format(r"\Pic" + sheet.name+str(i)))
                mail.HTMLBody = "<br><br><h4> <img src=""cid:{}"" height=""300"" width=""870""><br>".format(r"\Pic" + sheet.name+str(i))
workbook.Close()                
del workbook
del excel
print("Done")
```

Currently, only the last image is being embedded. I need all exported images being embedded in mail body.